# regex filter text match in react giving null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the Project Name from record description like below

```
Project Name:[xyz 28912] omiture
```

Here's my code

```
record.description.forEach(tempDescription => {
 var projectTitle = tempDescription.text.match(/Project Name:.*?(?=\s+Following)/gs);
 console.log(projectTitle); // giving null    if(null !== projectTitle    &&  undefined !==projectTitle){    var titleArr = projectTitle[0].split(":");
 console.log(titleArr)
} })
```

I need help on it

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please show input and expected output. Your regex will never math the suggested input you have given us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

https://regex101.com/r/v5NoQ1/1

```
/Project Name:\[(.*?)\]\s+(.*)/gs
```

as in

```js
const record = {
  description: [
  { text: "Project Name:[xyz 28911] omiture" },
  { text: "Project Name:[xyz 28912] omiture" },
  { text: "Project Name:[xyz 28913] omiture" }
  ]
};

const re = /Project Name:\[(.*?)\]\s+(.*)/gs;
const projectNames = record.description.map(tempDescription => {
  const [a] = tempDescription.text.matchAll(re);
  return {
    name: a[1],
    desc: a[2]
  }
})
console.log(projectNames)
```